# What does this symbol do in C?

Tags: c, pointers, operators, suffix-tree

I'm learning about suffix tree and I found a site explaining it very well, but just the theory. The code is well commented but I found what seems to be an operator I will leave the site where I found it and also the code snippet I'm trying to understand what this "operator" does.

Site: https://acervolima.com/suffix-tree-application-4-construir-array-de-sufixo-de-tempo-linear/

```c
// There is no outgoing edge starting with
// activeEdge from activeNode
    if (activeNode->children] == NULL){
        //Extension Rule 2 (A new leaf edge gets created)
        activeNode->children] = newNode(pos, &leafEnd);
    }
```

What the `]` after `activeNode->children]` does?

```c
void extendSuffixTree(int pos){
    /*Extension Rule 1, this takes care of extending all
    leaves created so far in tree*/
    leafEnd = pos;

    /*Increment remainingSuffixCount indicating that a
    new suffix added to the list of suffixes yet to be
    added in tree*/
    remainingSuffixCount++;

    /*set lastNewNode to NULL while starting a new phase,
     indicating there is no internal node waiting for
     it's suffix link reset in current phase*/
    lastNewNode = NULL;

    //Add all suffixes (yet to be added) one by one in tree
    while(remainingSuffixCount > 0) {

        if (activeLength == 0)
            activeEdge = pos; //APCFALZ

        // There is no outgoing edge starting with
        // activeEdge from activeNode
        if (activeNode->children] == NULL){
            //Extension Rule 2 (A new leaf edge gets created)
            activeNode->children] = newNode(pos, &leafEnd);

            /*A new leaf edge is created in above line starting
             from  an existng node (the current activeNode), and
             if there is any internal node waiting for it's suffix
             link get reset, point the suffix link from that last
             internal node to current activeNode. Then set lastNewNode
             to NULL indicating no more node waiting for suffix link
             reset.*/
            if (lastNewNode != NULL)
            {
                lastNewNode->suffixLink = activeNode;
                lastNewNode = NULL;
            }
        }
            // There is an outgoing edge starting with activeEdge
            // from activeNode
        else
        {
            // Get the next node at the end of edge starting
            // with activeEdge
            Node *next = activeNode->children];
            if (walkDown(next))//Do walkdown
            {
                //Start from next node (the new activeNode)
                continue;
            }
            /*Extension Rule 3 (current character being processed
                is already on the edge)*/
            if (text[next->start + activeLength] == text[pos])
            {
                //If a newly created node waiting for it's
                //suffix link to be set, then set suffix link
                //of that waiting node to current active node
                if(lastNewNode != NULL && activeNode != root)
                {
                    lastNewNode->suffixLink = activeNode;
                    lastNewNode = NULL;
                }

                //APCFER3
                activeLength++;
                /*STOP all further processing in this phase
                and move on to next phase*/
                break;
            }

            /*We will be here when activePoint is in middle of
                the edge being traversed and current character
                being processed is not  on the edge (we fall off
                the tree). In this case, we add a new internal node
                and a new leaf edge going out of that new node. This
                is Extension Rule 2, where a new leaf edge and a new
            internal node get created*/
            splitEnd = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
            *splitEnd = next->start + activeLength - 1;

            //New internal node
            Node *split = newNode(next->start, splitEnd);
            activeNode->children] = split;

            //New leaf coming out of new internal node
            split->children] = newNode(pos, &leafEnd);
            next->start += activeLength;
            split->children] = next;

            /*We got a new internal node here. If there is any
                internal node created in last extensions of same
                phase which is still waiting for it's suffix link
                reset, do it now.*/
            if (lastNewNode != NULL)
            {
                /*suffixLink of lastNewNode points to current newly
                    created internal node*/
                lastNewNode->suffixLink = split;
            }

            /*Make the current newly created internal node waiting
                for it's suffix link reset (which is pointing to root
                at present). If we come across any other internal node
                (existing or newly created) in next extension of same
                phase, when a new leaf edge gets added (i.e. when
                Extension Rule 2 applies is any of the next extension
                of same phase) at that point, suffixLink of this node
                will point to that internal node.*/
            lastNewNode = split;
        }

        /* One suffix got added in tree, decrement the count of
            suffixes yet to be added.*/
        remainingSuffixCount--;
        if (activeNode == root && activeLength > 0) //APCFER2C1
        {
            activeLength--;
            activeEdge = pos - remainingSuffixCount + 1;
        }
        else if (activeNode != root) //APCFER2C2
            {
                activeNode = activeNode->suffixLink;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: That has to be a typo - the `]` should not be there.

Comment: Looks to be a failed find and replace. `children[pos]` is maybe what they meant or just `children`.

Comment: Need more context to be 100% sure what was intended. As it is, it's a syntax error.

Comment: I added the entire code to question

Comment: Thank you. @GeneralGrievance 's first postulation is probably correct.

Answer (score 1):

That's a typo; I think it should be

```
if (activeNode->children == NULL){
        //Extension Rule 2 (A new leaf edge gets created)
        activeNode->children = newNode(pos, &leafEnd);
    }
```

In other words if `children` doesn't exist, create it.